# SOQL - Where iD not in aggregate list

Tags: soql, aggregate

I can't quite get the syntax right on this.

I need the query under getAllBadges, last public of code, to exclude any badges found in the aggregate function. However I can't figure out the name of the list. I use Summaries on the VF page but that doesn't seem to work for this.

Any help?

The code has been trimmed to relevant pieces.

```
    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

//Aggregate Function
    public TrophyCaseController() {
//Get performance badges for individual user
        AggregateResult[] results = [
            SELECT Performance_Badge__c, 
                   MAX(Performance_Metric_Badge__r.ImageURL__c) badgeURL,
                   COUNT(Name) badgeCount, 
                   MAX(Id) BadgeId
              FROM Performance_Metric__c 
              WHERE User__c = :userIdStr 
              GROUP BY Performance_Badge__c
        ];
        Summaries = new List<Summary>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
            Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
        }   
    }

//LIst of earned performance badges
    public class Summary {
        public Integer BadgeCount { get; private set; }
        public String Badge { get; private set; }
        public String BadgeURL { get; private set; }
        public String BadgeId { get; private set; }

        public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
            badgeCount = (Integer) ar.get('badgeCount');
            BadgeURL = (String) ar.get('badgeURL');
            Badge = (String) ar.get('Performance_Badge__c');
            BadgeId = (String) ar.get('BadgeId');
        }
    }


//List of available badges
//Exclude the badges in the aggregate result above.
    public List<Performance_Metric_Badge__c> getAllBadges() {
        List<Summary> allbadges = getSummary();

        List<Performance_Metric_Badge__c> results = Database.query(
            'SELECT Id, Name, ImageURL__c ' +
            'FROM Performance_Metric_Badge__c ' +
            'WHERE Id NOT IN :allbadges '
        );
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a "getSummary" method in the code you posted. If you're trying to access the auto-getter for the variable you have then it should be `getSummaries()`.

However, I would recommend you change your last method to:

```
public List<Performance_Metric_Badge__c> getAllBadges() {

        List<Id> allbadgeIDs = new List<Id>();
        for (Summary sum : summaries) {
          allbadgeIDs.add(sum.badgeid);
         }

        List<Performance_Metric_Badge__c> results = [SELECT Id, 
                            Name, 
                            ImageURL__c 
                       FROM Performance_Metric_Badge__c 
                       WHERE Id NOT IN :allbadgeIDs];

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be close as the dev console stopped yelling but the other badges are still showing up in my results.

Comment: What do you mean by "other" badges? If you run your SoQL in the developer console, do you get all badges you want or extras?

Comment: Perhaps the "IN" clause is not correct. Change it to "WHERE Id IN :allbadgeIDs" and see if that's what you wanted...

Comment: Nope, it should be NOT IN. Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Then, assuming the Id field of Peformance_Metric_Badge__c matches the Id Field of Performance_Metric__c my code should work as written.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/tPtJFxza

Comment: Check your fields. I thnk this is a problem in the way your fields are matching one another. Ca we see a small data sample?

Comment: Thank you! That made me find it!  The first aggregate soql query was looking at the Id from Metric instead of Metric Badge.

Comment: Woot! Please mark the solution as accepted, pretty please... :D

Answer (score 2):

Applying the IN operator to an `Id` field requires that you hand a `List<Id>` (not `List<Summary>`)

What happens if you convert one into the other, in between your step 1 and your step 2?

```
//your code (1)
List<Summary> allbadges = getSummary();

//step one and a half
List<Id> badgeIds = new List<Id>();
for (Summary summary : allBadges) badgeIds.add(summary.BadgeId));

//your code (2)
List<Performance_Metric_Badge__c> results = [
    SELECT Id, Name, ImageURL__c
    FROM Performance_Metric_Badge__c
    WHERE Id NOT IN :badgeIds
];
```

Comment: I am getting stopped at Step 1 with error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: getSummary()"

Comment: You do not have a method defined for getSummary();

Comment: You just want to do what is outlined in the answer above in your getAllBadgesMethod except substitute the "allBadges" variable with the public "Summaries" list you populated in the constructor.